# How to avoid childrens of groupbox taking there default styles which are defined in resource or resourcedictionary in wpf

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

Style defined in Resource

```
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"/>

    </Style>enter code here
</Window.Resources>
```

In window i am adding a groupbox with child label .

```
<Grid>
    <GroupBox Header="Header">
        <GroupBox.Resources>

                <Style TargetType="{x:Type GroupBox}">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="white"/>
            </Style>
        </GroupBox.Resources>
        <Label Content="dsfdsfdsf" Foreground="Black"  />
    </GroupBox>
</Grid>
```

My Expected Result was Label taking background of white . But actually it is taking Red Background (that is defined in style of Resource )

If i set the style of the Label to explicitly  null it works fine

```
Label Content="dsfdsfdsf" Foreground="Black" Style={x:Null}
```

But Controls to GroupBox are dynamically added so i want to set
`Style={x:Null}` to all childrens that are being added to Group box

if i set OverrideDefalutStyle to True in Label the content of label is not comming ......................

```
Label Content="dsfdsfdsf" Foreground="Black" OverridesDefaultStyle="True"
```

Comment: There is a pain in WPF design that we cannot style the elements like what we do with CSS3. In this case the `Style` can just target ***exactly*** a type, not even the derived Types can inherit that style (e.g: a Style targeting Control will NOT be able to apply on elements deriving from Control). So for your scenario, unless you know before-hand all Types of your dynamically added elements, you will not have a fine solution using just pure XAML (without any custom attached property or hack using code behind).

Answer (score 0):

By setting

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type GroupBox}">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="White"/>
</Style>
```

you will set the background of all `GroupBox` controls within your GroupBox and the GroupBox itself to white.

So if you want to set/override the Background of all Labels within your GroupBox just add an additional Style to your GroupBox targeting `Label`

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type Label}">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="White"/>
</Style>
```

If you want to reset the style property of your `Label` just add an empty style definition to your `GroupBox`

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type Label}"/>
```

---

The next approach is used on your on risk :)

If you only want to reset the background color, you can do this trick/hack to reset:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type Label}">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{Binding Background.DefaultValue, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" />
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black" />
 </Style>
```

**Hint:** Instead of `Background.DefaultValue` you can also write `Background.ABC` the main thing here is that the binding goes wrong.

Answer (score 0):

That style in GroupBox.Resources has no effect on the GroupBox itself. The implicit GroupBox's style is the one of its closest ancestor on VisualTree. You put that style in the wrong place.

Or use Style property instead

```
<Grid>
    <GroupBox Header="Header">
        <GroupBox.Style>

                <Style TargetType="{x:Type GroupBox}">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="white"/>
            </Style>
        </GroupBox.Style>
        <Label Content="dsfdsfdsf" Foreground="Black"  />
    </GroupBox>
</Grid>
```